# Closed doesn't imply complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a norm  linear space.  If $X$ is banach space then subspace $Y$ is closed iff $Y$ is complete.

But if $X$ is not banach space then $Y$ is closed need not imply $Y$ is complete.

Can u give me such an example?

I took a non-banach space $C[0, 1]$ with integration norm. But I am unable to find such an example here.

Comment: Any normed space is closed with respect to itself.

Comment: I know but I want non-trivial example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the normed space $P$ of polynomials in $[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. This space is not complete, as we can find a squence that is Cauchy and converges to $e^x$ in $C[0,1] \setminus P$. Namely,

$$
p_n := 1+ x + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

converges to $e^x$ in $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm, so the sequence in $P$ must be Cauchy but it doesn't converge there. We also have that

$$
p_n \in \{p \in P : p(0) \geq 1 \} =: F,
$$

so in particular the closed set $F \subset P$ is not complete.

Comment: You forgot to divide by $n!$ in your sum.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Closed subspaces don't have to be complete. You could take any incomplete metric space and then the space is closed with respect to itself. However, for a subspace, take the rationals in any closed interval, which will be closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not complete.